# Finite and infinite 4-regular vertex-transitive graphs with identical $R$-balls

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, lo.logic

Consider the set of all 4-regular connected vertex-transitive graphs.

By compactness, for every integer $R \ge 0$, there is an integer $N_R$, so that for every 4-regular vertex-transitive graph of radius larger than $N_R$, there is an infinite vertex-transitive graph with identical $R$-balls.

Do we know any bounds on $N_R$?

Comment: Is this group theory, or graph theory?

Comment: If you choose a more informative title and tags, you will increase the chance that someone who can answer will see the question and respond.

Comment: Actually, vertex transitive graphs are closely connected to group theory.

Comment: I edited accordingly.

Comment: Obviously equivalent, but maybe useful for intuition: $N_R$ is the largest radius of a 4-regular vertex-transitive graph whose $R$-ball are not isomorphic to the $R$-ball in any infinite vertex-transitive graph. I have no idea even to prove that $N_R\gg R$.

Comment: Nice question! I think that the question has also a logic flavour so I added the tags: "logic" and "combinatorics"

Comment: Can't you make such an infinite 4-regular vertex-transitive graph by taking countably many disjoint copies of the finite graph? If that doesn't prove I misunderstand something, perhaps you should add a connectivity condition.

Comment: connectivity added

Comment: a lot is known if you also assume it is being edge-transitive, not only vertex-transitive. Then you have a nice "group amalgam", the free product of vertix stabiliser and edge stabiliser amalgamated with the stabiliser of vertex and an adjacent edge.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the question, but it is a bit long for a comment.

My aim here is to note that, if one works with Cayley graphs *with edges oriented and labeled by the corresponding generators $S=\{a,b\}$*, then it is known that the analogous number $N'_R$ grows at least exponentially fast with respect to $R$. (One can replace $4$ by some fixed integer in "$4$-regular", or equivalently $S$ by some larger fixed finite set.)

The basic observation is the following: if $G$ is a group with finite generating set $S$, then its Cayley graph has the same *labeled* $R$-ball as some infinite Cayley graph if and only if the group $\langle S\mid A\rangle$ if infinite, where $A$ are the group words of length less than $2R$ that are trivial in $G$.

Indeed, $\langle S\mid A\rangle$ is the largest group with the same $R$-balls as $G$, because every relation in $G$ that one can see in a ball of radius $R$ has length $\leq 2R$.

This observation leads to the following equivalent definition of $N'_R$.  Consider all presentations $\langle S\mid A\rangle$ for $A$ a set of group words of length less than $2R$ with respect to $S$. We get finitely many group presentations, some of infinite groups and some of finite groups. Then $N'_R$ is the maximal radius of those finite groups.

It is known that there are finite groups with relations of length $\leq R$ and radius $\geq e^{cR}$. For example the finite nonabelian simple groups, see the paper [Presentations of finite simple groups: a quantitative approach](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~alexlub/PAPERS/Presentation%20of%20Finite%20Simple%20Groups%20A%20Quantitative%20Approach/Presentation%20of%20Finite%20Simple%20Groups%20A%20Quantitative%20Approach.pdf) (or [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602508)) by Guralnik, Kantor, Kassabov and Lubotzky. One concludes that $N'_R \geq e^{cR}$ for labeled Cayley graphs.

For unlabeled Cayley graphs, I wonder whether the finite simple groups can be used to show that $N_R$ also grows at least exponentially. My gut feeling is that $N_R$ grows much faster.